# Cursor change when GVIM lost focus

Tags: gvim

In GVIM I use vertical thin line as my cursor by adding following line to my .gvimrc

```
set guicursor=a:ver13-Cursor
```

This works perfectly as long as window remained focused. As soon as GVIM window lost it focus cursor change to bad ugly transparent block. How can I prevent that. (This happens in all modes like insert, visual, ...)

I'm on linux-arch-gnome3-gvim

Thanks

[image]

#### EDIT1

As suggested by cristian there may be a autocmd that create this effect
[image]

Comment: do you have a CursorLost autocommand? Check `:verbose :au CursorLost`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for you reply. nice comment. Actually looklike my vim (8.0) doesn't have _CursorLost_ event (running your command return `E216: No such group or event!`) but I find a new event _FocusLost_. I edit my post and add it's response. I think creating an autocommand on Focus lost may help

Comment: Yeah, I actually meant `FocusLost`, that was a typo. Could disable the mentioned plugin and check if the problem still occurs?

Comment: I disable the plugin but unfortunately the result remained the same. I also installed a fresh vim on an other machine with no config but setting cursor yesterday and see same outcome there too. If it's not rude what is your gvim version. may be do an update fix it for me

Comment: This behavior is not caused by vim, but your windows manager (e.g. openbox). You should see the same effect when a terminal window looses focus.

Comment: @nst0022 wow. seeing the same in terminal is indeed intresting. still its a little odd that window manager do that. window manager just send lost focus to gvim right? I don't know much about wm so if I'm wrong please help me understand. my wm is mutter and I already change the source a little. I can change it again if it solve the issue